# remove color codes from console text output

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string which consists of color codes for some of the words. For example:

```
[38;2;139;0;0mHello [38;2;255;255;255m[38;2;128;128;128mWorld [38;2;255;255;255m
```

I need a way to remove these codes. Color code values are dynamics and keep changing but it has a pattern of **[38;2;r;g;bm**. The regular expression, using the above string, should return *'Hello World'*.

I tried regular expression `^.*$` so far but it did not work.

I would like to do this in Python, not Perl, sed or Bash.

Any suggestion how can it be done? Or a valid regex to replace with ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regular expression for those color codes then use the `Pattern.sub()` method, passing an empty string as the first argument, to remove those unwanted parts.

A regular expression which matches the pattern provided (**[38;2;r;g;bm**):

`\[\d{,3}(;\d{,3}){4}m`

Using this regular expression with the `sub()` method and the test string provided:

```py
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\[38;2(;\d{,3}){3}m")
>>> regex.sub("", "[38;2;139;0;0mHello [38;2;255;255;255m[38;2;128;128;128mWorld [38;2;255;255;255m")
'Hello World '
```