# remove color codes from list of lists before saving to file

Tags: python-3.x, console-application, sudoku, color-codes

Im working wiht a list of lists that ended up containing color codes surrounding integer elements in the sublists. This list of lists is meant to be printed into the console as a sudoku grid with gray cells by using a function that replaces the element already present, according to a coordinates list,  by the element surrounded by the color codes. However, it would be ideal if i could not save the color codes into the file by removing them priorly or not having them saved into a variable.

This is the function used to save into a file:

```
def board_saver(board,str_filename):
    filename = open(str_filename,'w')
    for i in board:
        if board.index(i) == 0:
            filename.write("[%s,\n" % i)
        else:
            filename.write("%s,\n" % i if board.index(i) in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] else "%s]\n" % i) 
    filename.close()
```

And this is the function used to read the same list of lists into python again, including, allowing further filling of the list of lists through the console:

```
def board_reader(str_filename):
    file1 = open(str_filename, 'r')
    board2 = eval(file1.read())
    print(type(board2))
    file1.close()
    return board2
```

Here is what i have been saving into a file:

```
[[5, 7, ' ', 8, 2, ' ', 4, ' ', ' '],
[3, '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m9\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', 6, ' ', 5, ' '],
[' ', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', 1, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 3, 7],
[2, '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m7\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', ' ', 8, 1, ' '],
[' ', 1, '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', ' ', 4, ' ', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', 6, ' '],
[7, 4, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m8\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', 5, ' ', ' ', ' ', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m5\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m9\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m', '\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m\x1b[1;37;40m \x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\x1b[0m']]
```

The functions that produce the list of lists above are:

```
    
    print("gray cells:",coordinates_list,)
    sudoku2 = board                            
    for i in coordinates_list: 
        element = i
        x = int(element[-1])
        y = int(element[0])
        
        if element == "{}{}".format(y,x) :
            sudoku2[y][x] = "\033[1;37;40m{}\033[0m".format(board[y][x])
    return sudoku2


def sudoku_printer(coordinates_list, board):
    """ Prints a board line by line with the elements from sudoku_board being placced in the
    {} place holders by the comprehention list in the format function. Because of board_fuser
    indexes qith zero are printed with a grey color"""
    board1 = board
    fused_board = board_fusor(coordinates_list, board1)
    print("fused board", board1)
    board_header2 = " 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9"
    row_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
    print("\n", board_header2)
    print("-"*37)
    for i, row in enumerate(fused_board):
        print(("|" + " {}   {}   {} |"*3).format(*[x if x != 0 else "{}".format(x) for x in row]),row_names[i])
        if i == 8:
            print("-"*37)
        elif i % 3 == 2:
            print("|" + "---+"*8 + "---|")
        else:
            print("|" + "   +"*8 + "   |")
```

When it should be/look like this:

```
[[5, 7, ' ', 8, 3, ' ', 4, ' ', ' '],
[3, ' ', ' ', 9, ' ', ' ', ' ', 5, ' '],
[' ', ' ', 1, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 3, 7],
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 7, ' ', 8, 1, ' '],
[2, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[1, ' ', ' ', ' ', 8, ' ', ' ', ' ', 6],
[' ', 1, ' ', ' ', 4, ' ', ' ', 6, ' '],
[7, 4, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 8, ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', 5, ' ', ' ', ' ', 5, 9, ' ']]
```

Can anyone help me please? What should I do to remove the color code part from the elements of the list of lists or to remove it after reading it from the file?
Is there an answer like: [remove color codes from console text output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099501/remove-color-codes-from-console-text-output)   to do that? I do not understand RegEx.

Comment: ANSI escape sequences can be matched with a regular expression, you can use `re.sub()` to remove them before processing the data.

Comment: For every element in every list, replace everything that matches `'[^']*'` with `' '`

Comment: @Bohemian, can you tell me more about the usage of the function to do that?

Comment: @Barmar, I have been trying to do that. It hasn´t been working so far

Comment: Why do you have color codes in the board data in the first place? You should add the colors in the output code, not in the raw data.

Comment: @Barmar, can you tell me more? I most lilely have been missusing regex patterns so far.

Comment: The regexp would be `\x1b\\[[;\\d]+[a-z]`

Comment: @Barmar, that is my problem, I can´t find out how to avoid writing them outside of the console. This is very strange. The function that fuses the color codes with the sublist elements only prints the list of lists. It should not go into a file like that.

Comment: You'll have to post more of your code if you want help fixing that.

Comment: Ok @Barmar. I am getting nothing at this point. I will write more code.

Comment: `sudoku2 = board` doesn't make a copy of the board. The two variables refer to the same lists. Use `import copy` and `sudoku2 = copy.deepcopy(board)`

Comment: @FranciscoVieira See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658439/256196)

Comment: @Barmar, it worked. Thank you so much. Now i can get to a different problem, which is continuing from a saved file.